# Angular RouterModule not woking in production

Tags: angular, routes

I have troubles getting my app working in production environment.

My app uses **angular-jwt from @auth0/angular-jwt**

If an user has an valid token, he will be forwarded to the MainScreenComponent, elsewhere he will be redirected to the login page.

```
import { AuthGuard } from './services/Authentication/auth-guard.service';
import { AuthGuardLogin } from './services/Authentication/auth-guard-login.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/Authentication/auth.service';
import { BrowserModule , HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './components/not-found/not-found.component';
import { NoAccessComponent } from './components/no-access/no-access.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { MainScreenComponent } from './components/main-screen/main-screen.component';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    NoAccessComponent,
    MainScreenComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
       { path: '', component: MainScreenComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
       { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuardLogin] },
       { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
     ]),
     JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: environment.whiteListDomains,
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
  AuthService,
  AuthGuard,
  AuthGuardLogin,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

if I use **ng serve** everything works like expected,
but after **ng build --prod**, I get an 404 if my initial URL is **https://my-site:4300/login**. 
In this case the RouterModule settings will be ignored.

If I type in **https://my-site:4300**, I will be redirected to **https://my-site:4300/login** and the login page will be displayed.

Any ideas?

========================

Update 31.10.2018:

Here is the AuthGuardLogin:

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardLogin implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()  === false) {
      return true; }

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

What I have now done, is hosting the website inside an Kestrel Server. 
Now it works perfect. Why? I don't know :-)!

By the way the Kestrel Server is hosted inside an Windows Service. So I can deploy that with our software package and install it via regular setup.

Best regards and thank you very much!!!

Comment: do you use `href="/"` on index.html page?

Comment: yes.  <base href="/">

Comment: is the `environment.prod.ts` properly configured? could you compare `environment.prod.ts` against `environment.dev.ts` or `environment.ts` ? perhaps some variable on environment files is creating the issue

Comment: Hi. Both are exactly the same except the production property.

Comment: lets have a look a this angular cli issue on git https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8515 maybe you are experiment something similar with the ServiceWorker and base-href

Comment: I have removed the ServiceWorker entry from the import section. Didn't change anything :-(.

Comment: Ok I may be way off base sorry, but is this deployed to the server?  On the server your server 404 routing has to be configure to route to your angular index.html so that the angular router can take over.

Comment: Thank you for your hint but I use the basic http-server. https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server. So there is nothing to configure. I also tried IIS with the same result.

Comment: What really is in `AuthGuard`? Post that as well!

Comment: Have you tried to properly setup your server? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: It's a problem with your server and how it loads those routes. For IIS, the solution is adding a new rule to web.config to handle loading the index.html file no matter what route is being hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to configure your server to rewrite unmatched URLs to your index.html.

If you are using IIS,

1. Select the website under Sites,
2. under IIS section, double-click on Error Pages
3. Select 404 Status Code from the list and open in edit mode
4. Select the radio button "*Execute a URL on this site*" and under URL textbox write "/" *(without double quote)*

You need to configure your production web server to always respond with the index.html whenever it detects a 404 - that way, Angular will always load and its routing service will handle the navigation on the client side.
Or else you will have to use Hash location strategy.

**EDIT:**
*Configuration for other servers:*

1. using live-server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

   `$live-server --entry-file=index.html`
2. using nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

   `error_page 404 /index.html`
3. Tomcat - configuration of web.xml.

   `<error-page>
         <error-code>404</error-code>
         <location>/index.html</location>
   </error-page>`

Comment: Thank you! Good idea! But I will not host that under IIS because it makes it harder to deploy it on a target machine via regular installer. IIS is not installed by default on most windows machines.

Comment: Correct. However, you can set this configuration on any server like (Apache, Unix) wherever you are deploying this application. The issue you have here is because of the nature of Single Page Application frameworks, such as Angular.

Comment: I have updated my answer with other server configuration options. Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: Yes this depends on the type of server you're running. I use IIS and the solution to this problem is adding a new rule to the web.config file.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem with a production environment when refresh was bugging out and couldnt identify the page.

I fixed it by using: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true
  })],

I am suggesting this solution since you said that when you typed the default url it worked and redirected in login, but when you typed /login it didnt.

useHash is used because angular is a spa and needs to load the main index.html first. In localhost and with webpack it works fine, but when you serve your app through  a server you need to go throught the index.html on refresh and when you directly hit a url when not using the angular router.

Your urls will become a little ugly though because a # is going to be added before each url. For example domain/login will become domain/#/login

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for your hint. If I now load the url with the login route the first time, I will also get the error. But if its cached it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding file `src/web.config` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It works form me as expected. I also added `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }` to `app.module.ts`, and `<base href="/">` to `index.html` but not shure that it's relevant.